# ScrollPanel with movieclips, does not show up

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scrollpane

I'm trying to get a scrollpane going with some movieclips, but as soon as i set the source of the sP, the content vanishes...

Code below:

```
public class main extends MovieClip {
    var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function main() {
        // constructor code

        addChild(container);
        sP.source = container;


        mc = new objOferta();
        mc.x = 0;
        mc.y = 0;
        nextYPos =mc.height + 1;
        container.addChild(mc);

        mc2 = new objOferta();
        mc2.x = 0;
        mc2.y = nextYPos;
        container.addChild(mc2);



        sP.update();



    }
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with your code, only is that your sprite container has no height and width, so instead of doing this

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

you can make a custom moviclip with some height width (so you dont have to code the container) or set height and width of your sprite based on no of items it has like it it has some 5 items of 50 height each

```
container.height = 5 * 50;
```

also you can check the fla here

http://ashwani.50webs.com/scrollpane.fla